# can't access css and js folder when deploying liftweb project on heroku

Tags: scala, heroku, jetty, lift

I have a liftweb App that I can run correctly on jetty in localhost using sbt (`container:start`), I can get all my CSS and JS behavior and I can access to my CSS file via URL `localhost:8080/css/style.css`.

But after deploying it on Heroku I can't get CSS style on my pages and when I try to get my CSS file from URL I get 404 page.

this is my class Go.scala declared in Procfile:

```
object Go extends App {
  val port =
    if(System.getenv("PORT") != null) System.getenv("PORT").toInt
    else 8080

  val server = new Server
  val scc = new SelectChannelConnector
  scc.setPort(port)
  server.setConnectors(Array(scc))

  //val context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/", ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS)
  val context = new WebAppContext()
  context.setContextPath("/")
  context.addServlet(classOf[DefaultServlet], "/");
  context.addFilter(classOf[LiftFilter], "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST))
  context.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp")

  server.setHandler(context);

  server.start()
  server.join()

}
```

I tried to add this part of code in my Boot.scala but it doesn't work:

```
ResourceServer.allow {
  case "css" :: _ => true
  case "js"  :: _ => true
}
```

Comment: You may want to ask on the lift mailing list